# How to properly make a LINQ query with clauses based on complex calculated data

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I have a pretty vast experience with LINQ to Entities and LINQ to SQL but this query is making my head burn.

I need some guidance on how to successfully create a clean LINQ to Entities query, when it has conditional clauses based on calculated columns, and when projecting the data into an object, to also use that calculated columns.

The projected results class is the following:

```
public class FilterClientsResult
{
    public enum ClientType
    {
        ALL,
        LIST,
        VIP
    }

    public int ClientId { get; set; }        

    public string Document { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ClientType Type { get; set; }

    public int Visits { get; set; }
}
```

Then the data comes from a primary source and 3 complimentary sources.

The primary source is the Client entity, that among all its properties, it has all the projected properties, with the exception of the last 2 (Type and Visits)

The other sources are:

`Subscription`, where 1 `Client` can have many `Subscription`.

`ClientAccess`, where 1 `Subscription` can have many `ClientAccess`.

`GuestListClient`, where 1 `Client` can have many `GuestListClient`.

So the `ClientType Type` property is set to `FilterClientsResult.ClientType.ALL` when that `Client` is related with both `ClientAccess` and `GuestListClient` entities.

It's set to `FilterClientsResult.ClientType.VIP` when that `Client` is related only to `ClientAccess` entities, and `FilterClientsResult.ClientType.LIST` when that `Client` is only related to `GuestListClient` entities.

Then the `Visits` property is set to the sum of `ClientAccess` and `GuestListClient` entities that the `Client` is related to.

So the query I need should be capable of filtering clients by `FilterClientsResult.ClientType` but also projecting that `FilterClientsResult.ClientType`.

And I also need to do filtering by a `Visits` range, but also projecting that `Visits` value.

So, what is the optimal way to build a query like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works best with query syntax, using the `let` keyword to store intermediate results as variables:

```
from c in Clients
let vipCount = c.Subscriptions.SelectMany(s => s.ClientAccesses).Count()
let listCount = c.GuestListClients.Count()
select new FilterClientsResult {
        c.ClientId,
        ...
        Type = vipCount > 0 ? listCount > 0 ? ClientType.ALL 
                                            : ClientType.VIP 
                            : listCount == 0 ? 0 
                                             : ClientType.LIST,
        Visits  = vipCount + listCount
    }
```

(not syntax checked)

Notice that the `ClientType` enum must be known to EF, otherwise you first have to project the required properties where `Type` is an `int`. Then, after an `AsEnumerable()`, cast the int to the enum.

Also notice that there is an indecisive value when both counts are 0.

Comment: Thanks for the `let` suggestion, it might be the best path for building this complex query. And if the sum of the counts is 0, that wont actually pass the where clauses, as this query should only get clients that have some ClientAccesses or GuestListClient relationships.